# How to create a reverse proxy with Nginx for my vps?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, vps

I'm trying to create a personal website with Angular. I need to pull some data from a few apis for a dashboard. An example api I'm using is https://api.alternative.me/fng/?limit=1. In development I was able to create a proxy.conf.json file to pass the CORS errors I would get for trying to GET from the api. However in production, this way wont work, so I have decided to use a vps and to create a reverse proxy with nginx. I have been able to get my website to show by building my app, and moving the dist folder contents into /var/www/html, so that nginx can use my index.html file. I'm having trouble now with my reverse proxy. I created a new file called reverse-proxy.conf, in the path /etc/nginx/sites-available, and have this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name {{my_vps_ip_address}};

location /alternative/ {
    proxy_pass https://api.alternative.me;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
}
```

When I go to my ip address in the browser, and to my dashboard route, and try to pull from the api, I get a message from my browser asking me to sign in, and saying my connection is not private. I have linked my sites-available to sites-enabled. Also I have not touched the nginx.conf file. The only changes I've made to my vps so far is uploading my files into the /var/www/html folder, and creating this reverse-proxy.conf file. I haven't changed the contents of the default file (/etc/nginx/sites-available/default). I also set permissions for the firewall. Is there something I am missing in my conf file? Thanks.

Comment: Would you please add the `access.log` for `curl -I --location my_vps_ip_address/alternative/`?